# Why does 5.0 == 5L return me a true?

Tags: java, equality

```
System.out.println(" answer is " + (5.0==5L));
```

This returns `true`!
It should return a `false` value because two different types are being compared.
Even though the `double` is compared to a `long` value!

Comment: Tastes differ but I actually prefer the expression evaluating to true.  What is happening is that the `long` is converted to  `double` and then the comparison is carried out in the obvious way.

Comment: Since they both happen to be numbers and since you're actually invoking the comparison in your code, Java assumes you want to compare them as numbers, converts the long and attempts to do the comparison. What would be the point of having an operator that compiles (`double==long`) but returns a constant value (`false`)?

Comment: using == operator with unboxing effect probably converts rvalue to the type of lvalue. in your case long is converted to double. It's also about the compiler's smartness. Think about what you wanted if had 5.6 == 5L

Comment: It would be _really confusing_ if it would return `false`! A compile error, perhaps, but not false!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two operands are going through *binary numeric promotion* as per [JLS section 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) in order to get to a single type for both operands.

The rules are like this:

> - If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> - Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>   - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
>   - ...
> - ...

Your second operand is of type `double`, so the `long` value is implicitly converted to `double`, then the two `double` values are compared - and they're equal.

Answer (score 4):

When comparing `long`s to `double`s, the `long` is promoted to a `double`, and then the two are compared. Since both are equal to five, the result is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

It returns true because it is comparing two types of "primitive variables". And if they are the same value, it works.

In comparison, using "==" on "object variables" returns true if the reference is to the same object, for example

```
Object a = new Object();  
Object b = a;
//then a==b is true
```

But:

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = new Object();
//then a==b is false
```